# Apache webserver - What happens to requests, when all worker threads are busy

Tags: apache, queue, request

As far as I researched, the scenario when all worker threads are busy serving requests, what happens to the requests that comes next.

1. Do they wait?
2. Is this related to some configurable parameters?
3. Can I get the count of such requests ?

Adding to this please can you explain or give a link where I can get a clear picture of request processing strategy of Apache webserver?

Thanks for Looking at!!

Comment: Please select one of the answers as the answer to your thread.

Comment: I don't think cbroughton meant a random one

Answer (score 9):

When all Apache worker threads are busy, the new request is stalled (it waits) until one of those worker threads is available.  If the client gives up waiting, or you surpass the maximum wait time in your configuration file; it will drop the connection.

Comment: *Additional to the post from cbroughton:* You should have a maximum of 500 request (this strongly depends of your Servercapacity). Here is a link for further reading [MaxKeepAliveRequests](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#MaxKeepAliveRequests)

Comment: I have a message sending application who sends SMS requests to apache, I want to monitor how many such requests are pending and queued to be served. So that 1) slow down message rate at sending agent, 2) increase throughput at SMSC.

Comment: Official Apache documentation for what the answer contains: [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html#maxrequestworkers).

Answer (score 3):

This answer is given in 2015. So I talk about apache httpd 2.4.

1. They wait because the connection is queued on the TCP socket (the connection is not ACKed) Although the default length of the backlog may be set way too high on linux boxes. This may result in connections being closed [due to kernel limits being in place](https://ryanfrantz.com/posts/apache-tcp-backlog.html).
2. [ListenBacklog](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html#listenbacklog) (with caveats. See 1.)
3. This is described [here](https://ryanfrantz.com/posts/apache-tcp-backlog.html). With lots of interesting stuff.

Read through [Apache TCP Backlog by Ryan Frantz](https://ryanfrantz.com/posts/apache-tcp-backlog.html) to get the glory details about the Apache backlog.