# Queueing request from the server [Apache]

Tags: php, mysql, apache, apache2

I have an auction website project, it is now being used for almost 2 months already.
The only problem right now is that, sometimes the request from the client is delayed for 2-3 seconds. Let say someone make a bid at 00:00:01, the request was received after 3 seconds, meaning the auction is now closed and that bid cannot be process anymore. I am sure that a specific auction is still active when someone make a bid, since I made a validations and not to allow the user to bid if the auction is already closed.

`user   date/time of bid request was received   date/time auction closed

ABC     2012-07-16 15:08:48                     2012-07-16 15:08:46`

I also monitor the ping latency using ping - t . The request timeout appear frequently same time when this problem occured. Normally the average time is less from 6ms - 100ms only

Anyway this happen once or twice a day at a random time.
I am not sure what trigger this problem, I tried to searched and some of them are saying that increasing the MaxClient (changed from 150 to 256.) can fix this, but its not.

PHP, Mysql, Windows server, Apache

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the latency you are describing depends on the server capacity, the net load and the current server load. if it happens only twice a day than it could be just a statistical outlier. In my point of view you cant do much about it but to provide an better internet connection or an faster server.

see this post for further reading [Apache webserver - What happens to requests, when all worker threads are busy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963460/apache-webserver-what-happens-to-requests-when-all-worker-threads-are-busy)

Comment: I will try this, thanks! If someone also experience this and was able to solve this issue please let me know